# Rails AR Date Range Query - Daylight Saving - Overlap

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

I have a Rails 3 application, how would one avoid an overlap happening due to daylight saving?

My problem is that I am having a form that generate reports. Auditing an inconsistency I noticed that a bunch of transactions show up in the week ending in March 11th also show up in the Week starting on March 12th.

The problem boils down to some thing like this...

```
Time.zone.parse('2018-03-11').to_datetime.end_of_day.utc
 => Mon, 12 Mar 2018 07:59:59 +0000 
Time.zone.parse('2018-03-12').to_datetime.beginning_of_day.utc
 => Mon, 12 Mar 2018 07:00:00 +0000
```

The 1 hour overlap above seem to be where my problem lies. When checking date ranges (see actual code below) how can I avoid this overlap.

#### Actual Code

Here is the actual code that resemble filtering by date.

```
  scope :filter_date, lambda { |starts, ends, date, transaction_type = :transaction|
    _scope = scoped


    starts = Time.zone.parse(starts).to_datetime        if starts.class == String and starts.present?
    ends   = Time.zone.parse(ends).to_datetime.tomorrow if ends.class   == String and ends.present?

    begin
      case date
      when 'settled'
        transaction_type == "batch" ? date_field = 'deposited_at' : date_field = 'settled_at'
        _scope = _scope.order('transactions.'+date_field+' DESC')
        _scope = _scope.where("transactions."+date_field+" >= ?", starts) if starts.present?
        _scope = _scope.where("transactions."+date_field+" < ?", ends)   if ends.present?
      else # created, nil, other
        _scope = _scope.order('transactions.created_at DESC')
        _scope = _scope.where("transactions.created_at >= ?", starts) if starts.present?
        _scope = _scope.where("transactions.created_at < ?", ends)   if ends.present?
      end
    end
    _scope
  }
```

#### Stack

- Ruby 2.1
- Rails 3.2
- PG

#### Question

How can I overcome this overlap of time where the daylight saving takes effect.

Comment: Why do you think you really need to do anything with it? You should keep in mind, that it's not a bug in your code. It's a bug in the world itself. Looking from conceptual point of view these transaction really took place in both weeks :( If you are still absolutely sure, that we need to do smth with it, then I will follow up with some solution

Comment: @AntonTkachov I didn't know this was a thing until guys from accounts raised a flag that weekly reports had inconsistencies with generated reports. The weekly reports summed up were off with the monthly reports.

Comment: I think it makes sense to discuss them how they handle such discrepancies on their side. Describe them an issue and get some feedback about their vision of possible solution. Because your code works fine and absolutely logical. In the meanwhile I will think about some hack, how to handle this :)

Comment: Wrote a solution. I hope you will keep me posted

Comment: Does my answer helped you?

Answer (score 0):

Try this solution. I think it should solve your issue:

```
scope :filter_date, lambda { |starts, ends, date, transaction_type = :transaction|
  _scope = scoped

  if starts.class == String and starts.present?
    starts = Time.zone.parse(starts)
    starts += 1.hour if starts.dst?
    starts = starts.to_datetime
  end

  if ends.class == String and ends.present?      
    ends = Time.zone.parse(ends) + 1.day
    ends += 1.hour if ends.dst?
    ends = ends.to_datetime
  end

  begin
    case date
    when 'settled'
      transaction_type == "batch" ? date_field = 'deposited_at' : date_field = 'settled_at'
      _scope = _scope.order('transactions.'+date_field+' DESC')
      _scope = _scope.where("transactions."+date_field+" >= ?", starts) if starts.present?
      _scope = _scope.where("transactions."+date_field+" < ?", ends)   if ends.present?
    else # created, nil, other
      _scope = _scope.order('transactions.created_at DESC')
      _scope = _scope.where("transactions.created_at >= ?", starts) if starts.present?
      _scope = _scope.where("transactions.created_at < ?", ends)   if ends.present?
    end
  end
  _scope
}
```

Comment: @Ziyan Junaideen Have this helped you?